# Not able to use Cache in Google App Engine - Getting com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine project wherein I am trying to cache some data in my APIs.

Below is how I try to use the cache in my code

```
try {
        CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance()
                .getCacheFactory();
        cache = cacheFactory.createCache(Collections.emptyMap());
        LOG.info("Cache Created");
        cache.put(key, value);
    } catch (CacheException ex) {
        LOG.error("cache exception encountered:{}", ex);
    }
```

I get the following exception

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make
>   API call memcache.Set in a thread that is neither the original request
>   thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
>
> at
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:175)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:172)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.put(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:69)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.stdimpl.GCache.put(GCache.java:157)
>   ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.54.jar:na]

The app engine dependency that I have added in my pom is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.54</version>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Apparently appengine-api-1.0-sdk doesn't mix well with AppEngine Flex or standard J8. Consider using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java or the Discovery API